# React-Select losing focus for custom component "ValueContainer"

Tags: reactjs, react-select

We have a use case where we have to render multiple different versions of the value container for the multiselect dropdown depending on how many options are selected. The code snippet below shows one of the cases. Another version of this renders a `<SingleValue />` instead of placeholder.

```
<ValueContainer {...props}>
    <Placeholder {...props}>
    {!props.selectProps.inputValue && `${length} selected`}
    </Placeholder>
    {children[1]}
</ValueContainer>
```

This seems to be working well, however we lose keyboard navigation upon selection of one of the options. Am I forgetting to pass certain props or a ref?

An example of dropped keyboard navigation for custom ValueContainers can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/rjvkzk1nn?from-embed

Answer (score 9):

Keyboard is not working anymore because you miss the `Input` component that is focused when you open the `Menu`.

`ValueContainer` has two objects when there's no value selected:

- `Placeholder`
- `Input`

when you select one (or multiple) value(s) then it changes for:

- `SingleValue` or `MultiValue`
- `Input`

with your previous example, you were removing those two.

To keep the keyboard features, you need to keep the `Input` component. The following code is a combination of your code and expectation and keeping the `Input` component:

```
const ValueContainer = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const { getValue, hasValue } = props;
  const newChildren = _.cloneDeep(children);
  const nbValues = getValue().length;
  newChildren[0] = `${nbValues} items selected`;

  if (!hasValue) {
    return (
      <components.ValueContainer {...props}>
        {children}
      </components.ValueContainer>
    );
  }
  return (
    <components.ValueContainer {...props}>
      {newChildren}
    </components.ValueContainer>
  );
};

const options = [
  { label: "label 1", value: 1 },
  { label: "label 2", value: 2 },
  { label: "label 3", value: 3 },
  { label: "label 4", value: 4 }
];

function App() {
  const components = { ValueContainer };
  return <Select isMulti components={components} options={options} />;
}
```

[Live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-custom-valuecontainer-qurbx).

Comment: Does this work if we have 1 or more values are selected as default?

Answer (score 8):

It turns out that you should put the custom value container outside the render

```
const CustomValueContainer: React.FC = props => (
  <components.ValueContainer {...props} />
);

const App = () => {
  const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        options={options}
        value={selectValue}
        closeMenuOnSelect={false}
        onChange={value => setSelectValue(value)}
        components={{
          ValueContainer: CustomValueContainer,
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2810#issuecomment-569117980

Comment: way to go. did the trick!

Answer (score 4):

My solution is simple, React is not complaining about missing `key` prop and web browser won't hang.

imports

```
import Select, { components } from 'react-select'
```

`ValueContainer` function

```
  const ValueContainer = ({ children, ...props }) => {
    const length = children[0].length
    let tmpChildren = [...children];
    if(length >= 2){
      tmpChildren[0] = `${length} languages`
    }
    return (
      <components.ValueContainer {...props}>{tmpChildren}</components.ValueContainer>
    );
  };
```

`<Select/>` component

```
<Select
      isMulti
      components={{ ValueContainer }}
      classNamePrefix="simplelocalize-select"
      placeholder="Showing all languages"
      closeMenuOnSelect={false}
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had something like the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ReactSelect, { components as defaultComponents } from 'react-select';

export default function Select({ label, components, ...props }) {
  const renderValueContainer = ({ children, ...valueContainerProps }) => (
    <defaultComponents.ValueContainer {...valueContainerProps}>
      {label}
      {children}
    </defaultComponents.ValueContainer>
  );

  return (
    <ReactSelect
      {...props}
      components={{ ...components, ValueContainer: renderValueContainer }}
    />
  );
}
```

As `renderValueContainer` was inside the component, its reference would change after every render, making react-select get confused about the container focus. To avoid that I wrapped the function in an `useCallback` so that its reference doesn't change at all through the component's lifecycle.

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import ReactSelect, { components as defaultComponents } from 'react-select';

export default function Select({ label, components, ...props }) {
  const renderValueContainer = useCallback(({ children, ...valueContainerProps }) => (
    <defaultComponents.ValueContainer {...valueContainerProps}>
      {label}
      {children}
    </defaultComponents.ValueContainer>
  ), []);

  return (
    <ReactSelect
      {...props}
      components={{ ...components, ValueContainer: renderValueContainer }}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ValueContainer = ({
  children,
  ...props
}: any) => {
  const currentValues = props.getValue();
  let selectedItemsLength = 0;
  let toBeRendered = children;
  if (currentValues.length >= 3) {
    toBeRendered = [children[0].slice(0, 3), children[1]];
    selectedItemsLength = currentValues.length - 3;
  }

  if (selectedItemsLength >= 1) {
    return ( <
      components.ValueContainer { ...props
      } > {
        toBeRendered
      } + {
        selectedItemsLength
      }
      selected <
      /components.ValueContainer>
    );
  }
  return ( <
    components.ValueContainer { ...props
    } > {
      toBeRendered
    } <
    /components.ValueContainer>
  );
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.