# React Select - Multi Select custom way to display multiple options

Tags: reactjs, select, dropdown, react-select

I am looking to customize the multiselect and the way we create the display of showing selected options.

Right now, with many options selected the select component takes up a prohibitive amount of space for certain UIs. See example:

[image]

I'd like to utilize the out of the box chip display for selected options within the input, but I only want to show only a few selected options (like 3/4 max) and then add a "badge" count for the number of selected options that aren't shown in the value container in the input. The options that are selected but are past the max number of chips allowed to show in the input should show as selected within the dropdown list, while the chips that do show's values should *not* show in our dropdown.

I've implemented part of this with using a custom `ValueContainer` to show only the first few chip selections, and then adding a count of additional/"overflow" selections. I'm unsure of how I can utilize the prop `hideSelectedOptions` to achieve this to show selected items in the list *only* when my max is met without showing all of them since this prop takes a boolean.

[image]

Here's what I have so far: https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-react-select-sjtib

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select, { components } from "react-select";
import { colourOptions } from "./docs/data";
import "./example.css";

class CustomSelect extends Component {
  state = {
    values: []
  };

  handleChange = values => {
    this.setState({ values });
  };

  render() {
    const { values } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Select
          hideSelectedOptions={values.length < 3 ? true : false}
          isMulti
          options={colourOptions}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={values}
          components={{ ValueContainer }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomSelect;

const ValueContainer = ({ children, getValue, ...props }) => {
  let maxToShow = 3;
  var length = getValue().length;
  let displayChips = React.Children.toArray(children).slice(0, maxToShow);
  let shouldBadgeShow = length > maxToShow;
  let displayLength = length - maxToShow;

  return (
    <components.ValueContainer {...props}>
      {!props.selectProps.inputValue && displayChips}
      <div className="root">
        {shouldBadgeShow &&
          `+ ${displayLength} item${length != 1 ? "s" : ""} selected`}
      </div>
    </components.ValueContainer>
  );
};
```

Comment: Any solution? Looking for it too.

Comment: @jpcmf80 https://stackoverflow.com/a/65342821/1133169

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would personally keep `hideSelectedOptions={false}` and go for `styles` property usage (`options` property to be more exact) and setting `display: 'none'` for the ones which shouldn't be visible:

```
const styles = {
    option: (base, value) => {
        return (shouldBeShown(value) ? { ...base } : { display: 'none'});
    }
};
```

`shouldBeShown(value)` is a custom function for checking if the particular option should be shown.
In order to get option data you can use `value.data`.

Then you can set `styles={styles}` in `Select` component:

```
<Select
    hideSelectedOptions={false}
    isMulti
    styles={styles}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    options={options}
    value={values}
    components={{ ValueContainer }}
/>
```