# Multiple values React Select ValueContainer depending on whether input is focused

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have a multiple select. Instead of using the default behaviour I am showing the total selected items in the *input* when there are any values selected.

The problem is that I want also to be able to type for search when some items are selected. I have managed to do that by returning the last `children` item from `CustomValueContainer` . But it's still not enough.

What I would like to do is to show the total items when the input has no focus, and hide it when the input is focused. So I need to get the reference to the input value from my `CustomValueContainer` in order to see if it's focused or not. Any ideas?

This is my code https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hv89pn:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Select, { components as selectComponents, ValueContainerProps } from 'react-select';
import './style.css';

const CustomValueContainer = (props) => {
  const length = props.getValue().length;
  const children = props.children;

  return length ? (
    <selectComponents.ValueContainer {...props}>
      <>
        {length} selected
        {children.slice(-1)}
      </>
    </selectComponents.ValueContainer>
  ) : (
    <selectComponents.ValueContainer {...props}>{children}</selectComponents.ValueContainer>
  );
};

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <Select 
        options = {[
          {value: "1", label: "one"},
          {value: "2", label: "two"},
          {value: "3", label: "three"},
          {value: "4", label: "four"},

        ]}
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={value => this.setState({ value })}
        isMulti
        components={{ValueContainer: CustomValueContainer}}
        clearable={true}
        closeMenuOnSelect={false}
        openMenuOnFocus={true}
      />
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Note that `CustomValueContainer` needs to be declared outside the `render` method (it does not work otherwise), but it's possible to pass a paremeter to it from render, I just need to pass it as a property of React Select and retrieve it from `CustomValueContainer` using `props.selectProps`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65342821/1133169